# SQL-Union ALL and Except

Tags: sql, union, sql-except

I am seeing a strange behavior when I do except and union statements in SQL.

I have two tables

```
Select * from #old
```

Data looks like this

```
oid1    oid2    co
   1      11     1
   2      22     1
   3      33     1
   4      55     1

Select * from #new

nid1    nid2    co
   1      11     3
   2      22     1
   3      33     1
   4      44     1
   4      55     1
```

This is my final query

```
Select * from #old
    except
    Select * from #new
    union all
    Select * from #new
    except
    Select * from #old
```

and gives these records

```
oid1    oid2    co
   1      11     3
   4      44     1
```

Question I have is.. Shouldn't there be another row in this from the first except clause:

```
Select * from #old
except
Select * from #new
```

which is

```
oid1    oid2    co    
   1      11     1
```

Shouldn't the final query have 3 rows instead of only 2, since not all columns are the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to think that the query is interpreted as:

```
(Select * from #old
 except
 Select * from #new
)
union all
(Select * from #new
 except
 Select * from #old
)
```

But no.  It is interpreted as:

```
((Select * from #old
  except
  Select * from #new
 )
 union all
 Select * from #new
)
except
Select * from #old
```

This is equivalent to:

```
Select * from #new
except
Select * from #old
```

which is what your query returns.

This is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> If EXCEPT or INTERSECT is used together with other operators in an
>   expression, it is evaluated in the context of the following
>   precedence:
>
> 1. Expressions in parentheses
> 2. The INTERSECT operator
> 3. EXCEPT and UNION evaluated from left to right based on their position in the expression

Comment: Perfect, thank you so very much. Yes, that's exactly I was interpreting it, learned something new today. Didn't know about those operators rules. Thank you!!